# Determing the number of bytes ready to be recv()'d

Tags: select, blocking, libc

I can use `select()` to determine if a call to `recv()` would block, but once I've determined that there are bytes to be read, is there a way to query *how many* bytes are currently available before I actually call `recv()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your OS provides it (and most do), you can use ioctl(..,FIONREAD,..):

```
int get_n_readable_bytes(int fd) {
    int n = -1;
    if (ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &n) < 0) {
        perror("ioctl failed");
        return -1;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Windows provides an analogous ioctlsocket(..,FIONREAD,..), which expects a pointer to unsigned long:

```
unsigned long get_n_readable_bytes(SOCKET sock) {
    unsigned long n = -1;
   if (ioctlsocket(sock, FIONREAD, &n) < 0) {
       /* look in WSAGetLastError() for the error code */
       return 0;
   }
   return n;
}
```

The ioctl call should work on sockets and some other fds, though not on all fds.  I believe that it works fine with TCP sockets on nearly any free unix-like OS you are likely to use. Its semantics are a little different for UDP sockets: for them, it tells you the number of bytes in the next datagram.

The ioctlsocket call on Windows will (obviously) only work on sockets.

Answer (score 2):

No, a protocol needs to determine that. For example:

- If you use fixed-size messages then you know you need to read X bytes.
- You could read a message header that indicates X bytes to read.
- You could read until a terminal character / sequence is found.

Comment: Actually, even if you could determine the bytes available, you'd still need a protocol to know how to interpret those bytes... I was asking for a very specific purpose...

Comment: Fair enough; just trying to expand on the short answer of "No".