# How to check more than 1 byte is ready to be read from the windows socket?

Tags: c++

I was trying through looping around `ioctlselect` or `recv`, which is consuming time. Somebody suggested to use `select`. `select` is very fast. But problem is i should receive only after more than one byte is ready to be received. `select` is ready if one byte is also readable from the socket. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926341/determing-the-number-of-bytes-ready-to-be-recvd

Answer (score 2):

Use `select`, and put the socket in non-blocking mode. (See `fcntl`, it can do this for you.) Then, simply `recv` into a large buffer. If there is less data available, you'll get a short `recv`, and `recv` will return to you the number of bytes it read. If nothing is available, `recv` will fail, and `errno` will be `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN` (check for both).

`recv` **can** fail with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` **even if `select` says data is available.**

It is more efficient and easier to read as much as available, and then buffer in your code as needed.

**Edit:** oops, you're on Windows. Same idea, except you'll need to check Winsock's error codes, not `errno`, and `ioctlsocket` can put the socket in non-blocking mode. (I'm not sure if Windows has `fcntl` or not.)